# Definition of Property: Function vs Subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Wikipedia says:

> In mathematics, a property is any characteristic that applies to a given set. Rigourously, a property $p$ defined for all elements of a set $X$ is usually defined as a function $p:X\to \{\text{true},\text{false}\}$, that is true whenever the property holds; or equivalently, as the subset of $X$ for which $p$ holds; i.e. the set $\{x:p(x)=\text{true}\}$; $p$ is its indicator function.

Technically speaking, aren't the function and the subset definitions different? I think a function from $X$ to $\{\text{true},\text{false}\}$ is a subset of the Cartesian product of $X$ and $\{\text{true},\text{false}\}$, not just a subset of $X$. If I'm wrong, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the definitions of a function and a subset are different. As you say, a function $f: A \to B$ is often defined as a subset $S$ of $A \times B$, that satisfies the condition that for $x_1 \in A$, there is only one element in $S$ of the form $(x_1, y)$.

However, the definition you've got from Wikipedia doesn't seem to be defining a property as a function generally, but rather as a function $f$ whose preimage of $\{\text{True}\}$ is precisely the subset on which the property holds. Since $f$ is a function into a two element set, the preimage of $\{\text{True}\}$, which is a subset of $X$, completely characterizes the function. It is in this sense that the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So it's talking about the elements that map to true in a function and not the function itself?

Comment: In a sense. It seems to be saying that we can either think about the elements of $X$ where property $p$ holds by constructing a function $f$ from $X$ to $\{ \text{True}, \text{False} \}$ where $f^{-1}(\{\text{True}\})$ consists precisely of these elements, or we can just view them as a subset $S$ of $X$.